# R: How to Intersect multiple vectors that gives all possible combination

Tags: r, tidyverse

How to Intersect multiple vectors that gives all possible combination

Here is dummy data:

```
set1 <- c("g1", "g2","g3","g4")
set2 <- c("g1", "g2","g8")
set3 <- c("g17", "g4")
set4 <- c("g1", "g3")
set5 <- c("g5")
```

And is it possible to get all combination list? Tidyverse approach will be helpful.

#----Expected result----------------------------------

```
# set1 & set2 & set4
# "g1"

# set1 & set4
# "g2"

# set1 & set2
# "g2"

# set1 & set4
# "g3"

# set1 & set3
# "g4"

# set2
# "g8"

# set3
# "g8"

# set3
# "g17"

# set5
# "g5"
```

etc... I might missed some possible combination.

Thank you.

Comment: why is set1 & set2 not `g1, g2`??

Comment: Sorry i didn't get  your idea?

Comment: set1 intersect set2. should it not be g1 and g2? ie both g1 and g2 are present in set1 and set2. Or are you kind of doing some venn diagram?

Comment: Ah yes, of course, I will fix "expected result", and I am not visualizing venn diagramm, but i wanna get all possible overlapping between these sets. Is it possible?

Comment: It looks like for the individual sets, you want to see the `setdiff()` to the rest of the sets. e.g. for `set2` you show `"g8"` in your expected results. Can you clarify? This would change the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest saving the sets in a list, then you could iterate over the elements of the list, e.g.:

```
sets2intersect <- list(set1, set2, set3,set4,set5)

lapply(unique(unlist(sets2intersect)), function(i){
  which(sapply(sets2intersect, function(x) any(i == x)))
})

[1]]
[1] 1 2 4

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 4

[[4]]
[1] 1 3

[[5]]
[1] 2

[[6]]
[1] 3

[[7]]
[1] 5
```

If you want to rename your list, to know which element was used, you can do:

```
result<- lapply(unique(unlist(sets2intersect)), function(i){
  which(sapply(sets2intersect, function(x) any(i == x)))
})
names(result) <- unique(unlist(sets2intersect))

$g1
[1] 1 2 4

$g2
[1] 1 2

$g3
[1] 1 4

$g4
[1] 1 3

$g8
[1] 2

$g17
[1] 3

$g5
[1] 5
```

Comment: This does not match the output needed

Comment: Whatever you are doing can be accomplished by `unstack(rev(stack(list(set1=set1, set2=set2, set3=set3, set4=set4, set5=set5))))`

Comment: This is a nice simplification for my code, thanks @Onyambu

Answer (score 2):

```
l <- mget(ls(pattern = '^set\\d'))
map(seq(2, length(l)), ~combn(l, .x, \(x)
      list(reduce(x, intersect))%>%
        set_names(str_c(names(x), collapse = ' & ')),
      simplify = FALSE)) %>%
  unlist(FALSE) %>%
  unlist(FALSE) %>%
  keep(~length(.x)>0)

$`set1 & set2`
[1] "g1" "g2"

$`set1 & set3`
[1] "g4"

$`set1 & set4`
[1] "g1" "g3"

$`set2 & set4`
[1] "g1"

$`set1 & set2 & set4`
[1] "g1"
```

Comment: This is a great answer! To omit the individual sets, you could change `seq_along(l)` to `2:length(l)`

Comment: It also looks like OP wants the `setdiff()` between each individual set and the rest. I haven't figured out how to get that in {purrr}, but it looks like you could get ther pretty easily.

Comment: @DanAdams in the code above, change `intersect` to `setdiff`. Although note that `setdiff(a, b)` is not same as `setdiff(b, a)`

Comment: Thanks, that didn't quite work for me so I ended up with a `for` loop, but maybe you can get it over the finish line from there. Thanks.

Comment: @DanAdams how do you want to do a set difference of 3 sets?? Thats not right. You could do an intersection/union of 3 sets but not the difference

Comment: my updated answer gets what I *thought* OP was after. It identifies any values that are unique to a given set and reports if  `> 0`. So for example `Reduce(setdiff, c(l[2], l[-2])` Does that make sense? Can you do that in {purrr}?

Comment: @DanAdams I am not quite sure what you are looking for, but you could try `l %>%
  VennDiagram::get.venn.partitions() %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove_all(.x, fixed('.'))) %>%
  filter(count > 0) %>%
  unite(set,set, values, sep = ' = ') %>%
  {cat(.$set, sep= '\n')}
`

Comment: OK thanks, I will just ask a separate question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: @DanAdams probably you are looking for `map(seq_along(l), ~reduce(l[-.x], setdiff,.init = l[[.x]])) %>%
    set_names(names(l))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240781/discussion-between-dan-adams-and-onyambu).

Answer (score 2):

The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/15980284/jkupzig provides the non-empty set of intersections. If you want both empty and non-empty, you can use a similar approach for all possible

```
library(DescTools)
names_of <- c("set1", "set2", "set3", "set4", "set5")
twins <- CombSet(names_of, 2, repl=FALSE, ord=FALSE)
trios <- CombSet(names_of, 3, repl=FALSE, ord=FALSE)
quads <- CombSet(names_of, 4, repl=FALSE, ord=FALSE)
quint <- CombSet(names_of, 5, repl=FALSE, ord=FALSE)

quint
#>      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
#> [1,] "set1" "set2" "set3" "set4" "set5"
quads
#>      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
#> [1,] "set1" "set2" "set3" "set4"
#> [2,] "set1" "set2" "set3" "set5"
#> [3,] "set1" "set2" "set4" "set5"
#> [4,] "set1" "set3" "set4" "set5"
#> [5,] "set2" "set3" "set4" "set5"
trios
#>       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
#>  [1,] "set1" "set2" "set3"
#>  [2,] "set1" "set2" "set4"
#>  [3,] "set1" "set2" "set5"
#>  [4,] "set1" "set3" "set4"
#>  [5,] "set1" "set3" "set5"
#>  [6,] "set1" "set4" "set5"
#>  [7,] "set2" "set3" "set4"
#>  [8,] "set2" "set3" "set5"
#>  [9,] "set2" "set4" "set5"
#> [10,] "set3" "set4" "set5"
twins
#>       [,1]   [,2]  
#>  [1,] "set1" "set2"
#>  [2,] "set1" "set3"
#>  [3,] "set1" "set4"
#>  [4,] "set1" "set5"
#>  [5,] "set2" "set3"
#>  [6,] "set2" "set4"
#>  [7,] "set2" "set5"
#>  [8,] "set3" "set4"
#>  [9,] "set3" "set5"
#> [10,] "set4" "set5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off the great answer from @Onyambu and whith help in the comments, I've added the members unique to each set using `setdiff()` which it appears was included in OP's desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set1 <- c("g1", "g2","g3","g4")
set2 <- c("g1", "g2","g8")
set3 <- c("g17", "g4")
set4 <- c("g1", "g3")
set5 <- c("g5")


l <- mget(ls(pattern = '^set\\d'))

map(2:length(l),
      ~ combn(l, .x, \(x)
              list(reduce(x, intersect)) %>%
                set_names(str_c(names(
                  x
                ), collapse = ' & ')),
              simplify = FALSE)) %>%
  unlist(FALSE) %>%
  unlist(FALSE) %>%
  c(.,
    map(seq_along(l), ~reduce(l[-.x], setdiff,.init = l[[.x]])) %>% 
      set_names(names(l))
    ) %>% 
  keep(~ length(.x) > 0)
#> $`set1 & set2`
#> [1] "g1" "g2"
#> 
#> $`set1 & set3`
#> [1] "g4"
#> 
#> $`set1 & set4`
#> [1] "g1" "g3"
#> 
#> $`set2 & set4`
#> [1] "g1"
#> 
#> $`set1 & set2 & set4`
#> [1] "g1"
#> 
#> $set2
#> [1] "g8"
#> 
#> $set3
#> [1] "g17"
#> 
#> $set5
#> [1] "g5"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>